# Columns names from entity using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity

I was able to get the columns names by using this:

```
var props = typeof(FMCSA_NPR).GetProperties();
```

But it is also giving me the names of other tables which have a foreign relation with the specified table.

Is there a way by which I can only get the column names? What do we call column names when referring table as entity in Entity Model?

Comment: Why do you care which properties belong to the entity's table?

Comment: I only need to show table column names not the related foreign tables.

Comment: @ItiTyagi what if your entity has Complex Type, which is stored in same database table? E.g. `Address` property, which is stored into `Address_City` and `Address_Zip` columns?

Comment: I dont get what are complex types, all I know is I need to show only column names, and like address, I have split address into multiple fields.

Comment: @ItiTyagi See [Complex Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738472(v=vs.100).aspx). Also it's not possible to know whether property is mapped to database or not, if you are not using attributes for mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the non-navigation properties of entities by accessing the conceptual model (`CSpace`):

```
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var cs = oc.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(oc.DefaultContainerName, 
                                                 DataSpace.CSpace);

foreach (var entitySet in cs.EntitySets)
{
    var props = string.Join(",", entitySet.ElementType.Properties);
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", entitySet.Name, props));
}
```

(Where `db` is your DbContext object).